# 4 Functions find lowes/highest position and value

Tags: c, arrays, function, max, min

I don't get the right values, what am i missing? I have similar code on my other PC and it seems to work. Been working on it for a few hours analyzing, everything looks good as far as i can see, but i am missing something for sure.
I am getting max number = 22, max pos = 0, min number = 22, min position = 2

```
#include <stdio.h>

int findMaxPos(int *numbers, int length);
int findMinPos(int *numbers, int length);

int findMax(int *numbers, int length);
int findMin(int *numbers, int length);

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 100, 50, 20, 35 , 25, 22};

    printf("Max number = %d\nMax pos = %d\nMin number = %d\nMin position = %d", findMax(arr, 6), findMaxPos(arr, 6), findMin(arr, 6), findMinPos(arr, 6));
    getchar();

    return 0;
}

int findMaxPos(int *numbers, int length) {
    int maxPos = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] > numbers[maxPos])
            maxPos = i;
    }
    return maxPos;
}

int findMinPos(int *numbers, int length)
{
    int minPos = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] < numbers[minPos])
            minPos = i;
    }

    return minPos;
}

int findMax(int *numbers, int length) {

    int maxNr = numbers[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] > maxNr);
        maxNr = numbers[i];
    }

    return maxNr;
}

int findMin(int *numbers, int length)
{
    int minNr = numbers[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] < minNr);
        minNr = numbers[i];
    }

    return minNr;
}
```

Comment: Look at that extra semicolon: `if (numbers[i] < minNr);` effectively says: If the number is smaller than the current min. number, _do nothing_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra `;` after the `if` in `findMax` and `findMin` :

```
if (numbers[i] > maxNr);
```

Remove the `;` :

```
if (numbers[i] > maxNr)
```

Comment: Max position gets 0 and Min position 2

Comment: @Cutik : your `findMaxPos` and `findMinPos` functions don't have the same issue (no extra `;`), so they return the correct (expected) result : the largest number in the array (100) is at position 0, and the smallest number (20) is at position 2.

Answer (score 1):

Array positions start at [0], so your Max position and Min Position are right :

`Numbers[0] = 100`

and

`Numbers[2] = 20`

For max number and min number, as said by Sander De Dycker, you just have to remove the extra `;` at the end of your if statements in `findMax` and `findMin` functions.